# Understanding a mechanical drawing

Tags: connector, mechanical, drawing

I'm trying to understand this mechanical drawing. (Another one. I asked a question about mechanical drawings a while back.)

[image]

I can work out most of the dimensions, but the mount pads are confusing me. They have two numbers (0.7 and 1.2) beside them. They could be any size for what I know...!

The drawing is for an SH type connector.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 0.7 is the distance from the center of the smaller (contact) pads to the edge of the larger (mechanical) pad.

[image]

The 1.2 is the width of the larger pad.

[image]

Notice the dot both arrows point to.

**edit**
You'll often see the indication `BSC` next to one of the measurements. This means `Basic Spacing between Centers` and is a nominal value. Could have been given here next to the 1mm (pitch) value, or next to a 6mm value between centers of first and last pad.

Comment: I put some images to help clarify better.

Comment: The answer above "answers" the question to a point...
For me, if it's important enough to dimension to the header outline on Y why not tie it down by giving X dimension to the edge of the header outline?

Comment: @taf: Welcome! This site is not a forum, and posts are not ordered chronologically. Answers are supposed to address the question, and if you want to comment on a post there is a specific tool. I took the liberty to convert your post into a comment, I hope I guessed right about the referred post.

Answer (score 6):

They are actually 1.2 x 1.8.

[image]

The dimensioning could be a lot clearer.

I wish that they would dimension to the pad centres That is how most PCB packages work.

Comment: What was wrong with that? I thought I'd answered the question about the pad size.

Comment: I misclicked the minus button, could you make a null edit so I can upvote you?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer. I've edited it.

Comment: Thomas, you should be able to undo your vote by clicking the button again.

Comment: @stevenh I have done so. It appears someone else voted down too.